# How do I write a bat file to run a python prompt in CMD

Tags: python, batch-file

I basically want to write a batch file that will open and run a line e.g:

Open batch file → open CMD → input:

```
python s3cmd get <path> --access_key --secret_key
```

Comment: So read some tutorial about batch files. I found [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/batch_script/) with my search engine in one second. Your *do-my-work* question is off-topic on StackOverflow and shows no research. Be also aware of the [`PATH` variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable))

Comment: What happens when you put that line into a file and save it with the `.bat` extension?

Comment: Also, that tutorial is abysmal, please don't use it.

Comment: Please note that https://stackoverflow.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You may need:

```
@echo off

"python s3cmd get --access_key --secret_key"
```

- Create a new txt file.
- Copy paste the text above there.
- Save your changes and exit.
- Rename your file extension from `.txt` to `.bat`.